# How to do a conditional formatting on "if cell's value on the right is less than the value left cell" for a range of values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

[image]

I tried selecting the entire range (e.g. A2 to Z400), then put in the condition for instance: `=B2<A2` to hope that a "ranged" conditional format would apply, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

I can probably come up with a VBA solution, but I was hoping to have an built-in Excel method if possible

Answer (score 1):

Utilize conditional formating is indeed possible.

1. Select the desired range.
2. Select Conditional Formatting.
3. New Rule..
4. Use a forumla to determine which cells to format.

For the formula, enter

```
=IF(B1<A1;1;0)
```

Also, choose how you which to format.

This checks wheter B1 is smaller than A1. If true, it would return 1 which is boolean for true. This logical test should solve your issue. See screenshot below for the rule applied to range A1:B5.

[Rule applied to range A1:B5 EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk54F.png)

Comment: Might want to add a test for right-hand cell being blank, but definitely works.